# Does managed languages lock flush and reload variables of native libraries?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, locking

When we use locks in managed languages like **C#** and **Java**, we can always be sure we are dealing with the latest data.

Specifically in Java memory model, they have a guarantee called **Happens-before relationship**.
But I'm not sure what will happen with native libraries.

Say, I have **C** functions like this :

```
static int sharedData;      // I'm not declaring this as volatile on purpose here.

void setData(int data) {
    sharedData = data;      // Not using any mutex or the like.
}

int getData() {
    return sharedData;
}
```

I also have **C#** code like this :

```
// Thread 1
while( true )
    lock( key )
        setData( ++i );     // Calling a native C function using P/Invoke.

// Thread 2
while( true )
    lock( key )
        DoSomeJob( getData() );
```

As you see, if `sharedData` from **C** side is not declared as `volatile`, then is there still a guarantee that **Thread 2** can always get the latest value set by **Thread 1**?

Does the same apply to **Java** using **JNI** too?

Comment: so the question here is : do the memory-barrier semantics of .NET/JVM propagate over P/Invoke boundaries into unmanaged code? (I don't have the required knowledge, but I would ***assume*** a hard "no", with a caveat that the pipe will usually be so saturated by the time you've done a P/Invoke that you're unlikely to *observe* the CPU cheat very often)

Comment: @MarcGravell Exactly! That's what I'm asking. Thanks :)

Comment: As far as the JVM goes, it seems to implement memory barriers for locks e.g. on  linux_x86 using `lock`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/d58442b8abc1/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/orderAccess_linux_x86.hpp#l48 Which I assume propagates to native code as well.

Comment: @JornVernee Does the specification say anything about it? If not, we can't just assume the same could be true with all the other JVMs like Android's. But, anyway, it was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: The JMM seems to just talk about threads, and doesn't really make a distinction between threads in native code or Java code, neither does it make a distinction between Java-heap or native-heap memory so I'd assume the JMM applies to both.

Answer (score 1):

> As you see, if `sharedData` from C side is not declared as volatile, then is there still a guarantee that Thread 2 can always get the latest value set by Thread 1?

No, and marking it `volatile` has no effect on threading either way.

> Does the same apply to Java using JNI too?

Yes, and it also applies to PHP, Lua, Python, and any other language that can pull in a C library in that way.

To elaborate on your first question, the `volatile` keyword in C is not used for threading, it is used to tell the compiler *not* to optimize on that variable.

Take for example the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

static bool run; // = false

void do_run(void)
{
    unsigned long v = 1;
    while (run) {
        if (++v == ULONG_MAX) run = false;
    }
    printf("v = %lu\n", v);
}

void set_run(bool value)
{
    run = value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    set_run(true);
    do_run();
    return 0;
}
```

With optimizations turned on, the compiler might see a lot of areas to remove unnecessary code without side effect, and do so; for instance, the compiler could see that `unsigned long v` will always be `ULONG_MAX` in the `do_run` function and opt instead to simply return `ULONG_MAX`.

And in fact when I run `gcc -O3` on the above code, that's exactly what happens, with the `do_run` function returning immediately and printing `v = 18446744073709551615`.

If you were to mark `run` as `volatile`, then the compiler can't optimize that variable, which usually means it cannot optimize the areas of code with that variable in certain ways.

To wit, when I change `run` to `static volatile bool run;` and then compile using `gcc -O3`, my program now stalls waiting for the loop to iterate through 18446744073709551615 times.

---

That aside, when you make a call into an external library, the only thread-safety you have is that provided by the language utilized in that library.

For C, you must explicitly specify thread safety in functions. So for your code, even though you are utilizing the `lock` context in the managed code, it is *only* locking for the managed code and the C code itself is still not thread safe.

Take for example the following code:

#### C code

```
static volatile int sharedData;
static volatile bool doRun;
static pthread_t addThread;

void* runThread(void* data)
{
    while (doRun) {
        ++sharedData;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void startThread(void)
{
    doRun = true;
    pthread_create(&addThread, NULL, &runThread, NULL);
}

void stopThread(void)
{
    doRun = false;
}

void setData(int data)
{
    sharedData = data;
}

int getData(void)
{
    return sharedData;
}
```

#### C# code

```
// Thread 1
startThread();
while (true) {
    lock (key) {
        setData(++i);
    }
}

// Thread 2
while (true) {
    lock (key) {
        i = getData();
    }
}
stopThread();
```

In this code, when `lock (key)` is called, the only guarantee you have is that `i` will be protected in the C# code. However, since the `C` code is also running a thread (because thread 1 called `startThread`), then you do not have any guarantee that the `C#` code will be properly synchronized.

To make the C code thread-safe, you will have to specifically add a mutex or semaphore to suit your needs:

```
static int sharedData;
static volatile bool doRun;
static pthread_t addThread;
static pthread_mutex_t key;

void* runThread(void* data)
{
    while (doRun) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&key);
        ++sharedData;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&key);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void startThread(void)
{
    doRun = true;
    pthread_mutex_init(&key, NULL);
    pthread_create(&addThread, NULL, &runThread, NULL);
}

void stopThread(void)
{
    doRun = false;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&key);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&key);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&key);
}

void setData(int data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&key);
    sharedData = data;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&key);
}

int getData(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&key);
    ret = sharedData;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&key);
    return ret;
}
```

In this way, the underlying library calls are protected appropriately and any number of processes sharing the memory of this library will also then be thread-safe.

I should note that the above utilizes POSIX for thread synchronization, but the WinAPI, or the C11 standard mutex could also be utilized depending on your target system.

I hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time writing all this and I immediately upvoted! But I'm in doubt about two things here.. First, you're correct about volatile being just a keyword to 'tell the compiler not to optimize on that variable'.
Also we know, unlike Java's and C#'s, `volatile` in C is not designed for thread communication in the first place. Especially it has reordering problems with non-volatile variables so most of the case, using `volatile` for thread commucation is not suitable,
unless you're using Visual C++'s compiler, which implements `volatile` differently.

Comment: But making the compiler not to optimize results in volatile reads/writes not allowing caching in the CPU side and therefore, it's useful for Memory Mapping IO, and that also means,
at least `volatile` can solve visible problems between different threads.
So, I'm really curious what made you think `volatile` can't be used in my example code.

Comment: My second question. As for your "it also applies to PHP, Lua, Python, and any other language that can pull in a C library in that way.", is there any reliable reference you're referring to? I mean, you may be a very experienced programmer and what you are saying may be correct in the most cases, but I really want to make sure if there's any written spec about these.

Comment: If you see a Jorn Vernee's comment above, JVM's native C++ code implements memory barriers for locks, and that means reloads and flushes on the native side. I'm not sure that's a standard behavior in all managed languages, but at least this says something against your theory.

Comment: _So, I'm really curious what made you think volatile can't be used in my example code._ .. I'm not saying you can't or shouldn't use `volatile`, just that it has different meaning in C and does not apply to threading if you're adhering to the ISO C standard, which you should be for hardware portability. The MSVC compiler is not known for standards compliance, which is why if you are targeting MS platforms using C or C++, you should be strictly adhering to the ISO standard as much as possible, as well as using standard types (like `int32_t` or `int64_t` instead of just plain `int` or `long`).

Comment: _is there any reliable reference you're referring to?_ .. The opcodes that are called in the underlying interfaces for external libraries on Windows (like C#'s P/Invoke or Java's JNI) will call the WinAPI `LoadLibrary` if it's a C/C++ DLL, so beyond the individual language references and their underlying system calls, it's more simply that the language itself has nothing to do with it, the code could be another C# library, but just because you `lock`, you cannot explicitly expect _all_ functions within the lock to be safe .. If I'm understanding your confusion in my answer correctly ..?

Comment: Hmm.. As for the `volatile`, you're just restating obvious facts, which I already mentioned above. It's not designed for thread communication when it's first introduced,
and still not desired and recommended in many multi-threaded code either, but it's useful for some cases and also widely used in embedded C programming to communicate between threads.
I also said MSVC++'s compiler is different, but actually the only major difference is, it just prevents reorderring like the new atomic feature, and other characteristics are the same as others.

Comment: My actualy question was more like, "When will `volatile` break and why?". A volatile variable's standard and portable behavior is, it will always read from and write to the main memory.
That means threads will not use locally cached data which lead to the 'visibility problem'. If `volatile` is used in the example above, whenever the variable is accessed, reload and flush will occured.
These volatile accesses will slow down with a little bit of overhead, but will promise the latest data.

Comment: If you insist `volatile` doesn't work this way, other than thread communication, all the memory mapping I/O will break in embedded systems.
So, could you give me a specific example `volatile` won't work? What platform do you have in mind?

Comment: Also I'm not quite convinced by your second explanation. You are just assuming things. I personally think all the languages are just different syntax sugar. All get compiled at some point anyway.
We all know CPUs can only understand machine code. What we don't know is how a certain language's compiler translates a certain thing, and that's the question I'm asking here.
As you see the above comment, Java's Hotspot is written in C++. In Unity, it provides an option called IL2CPP which converts all the C# code into C++ code and then compiles it using a C++'s compiler.

Comment: What I want to say by these is, if a managed language's `lock` works simliar to `pthread_mutex_lock()`, then a managed language's memory-barrier semantics may propagate too.
Yes, I know, this may not true. But we can not say all the managed's locks don't work with unmanaged libraries at all, either. That's why I asked for the reliable reference.